# merging two relational pandas dataframes as single nested json output

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have two relational dataframes like the bellow.

df_doc:

```
|document_id| name|
+-----------+-----+
|          1|  aaa|
|          2|  bbb|
```

df_topic:

```
|   topic_id| name|document_id|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|          1|  xxx|          1|
|          2|  yyy|          2|
|          3|  zzz|          2|
```

I want merge them to a single nested json file like the bellow.

```
[
    {
        "document_id": 1,
        "name": "aaa",
        "topics": [
            {
                "topic_id": 1,
                "name": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document_id": 2,
        "name": "bbb",
        "topics": [
            {
                "topic_id": 2,
                "name": "yyy"
            },
            {
                "topic_id": 3,
                "name": "zzz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

That is, I want to do the reverse of what `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` does.

An answer using sqlite, is also OK.

NOTE: **Both df_doc and df_topic have columns "name" which have the same names but different values**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only 2 column `df_doc` use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for join new column `title` first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with convert to [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and then [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
s = df_doc.set_index('document_id')['title']
df_topic['title'] = df_topic['document_id'].map(s)

#filter all columns without values in list
cols = df_topic.columns.difference(['document_id','title'])
j = (df_topic.groupby(['document_id','title'])[cols]
             .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
             .reset_index(name='topics')
             .to_json(orient='records'))
print (j)

[{"document_id":1,"title":"aaa","topics":[{"name":"xxx","topic_id":1}]},
 {"document_id":2,"title":"bbb","topics":[{"name":"yyy","topic_id":2},
                                          {"name":"zzz","topic_id":3}]}]
```

If multiple columns in `df_doc` use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) instead `map`:

```
df = df_topic.merge(df_doc, on='document_id')
print (df)
   topic_id name  document_id title
0         1  xxx            1   aaa
1         2  yyy            2   bbb
2         3  zzz            2   bbb

cols = df.columns.difference(['document_id','title'])
j = (df.groupby(['document_id','title'])[cols]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='topics')
       .to_json(orient='records'))
```

EDIT: If same columns names is possible add parameter `suffixes` for add `_` to columns names for unique and last `strip` them:

```
df = df_topic.merge(df_doc, on='document_id', suffixes=('','_'))
print (df)
   topic_id name  document_id name_
0         1  xxx            1   aaa
1         2  yyy            2   bbb
2         3  zzz            2   bbb

cols = df.columns.difference(['document_id','title'])
j = (df.groupby(['document_id','name_'])[cols]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='topics')
       .rename(columns=lambda x: x.rstrip('_'))
       .to_json(orient='records'))
print (j)
[{"document_id":1,"name":"aaa","topics":[{"name":"xxx","name_":"aaa","topic_id":1}]},
 {"document_id":2,"name":"bbb","topics":[{"name":"yyy","name_":"bbb","topic_id":2},
                                         {"name":"zzz","name_":"bbb","topic_id":3}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I edited my question. Both df_doc and df_topic have columns which have the same name but different values.