# Aws Athena / Presto - nest two tables

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'd like to use aws athena to nest two parquet tables such that:

Table A

```
|document_id| name|
+-----------+-----+
|          1|  aaa|
|          2|  bbb|
```

Table B

```
|   topic_id| name|document_id|
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|          1|  xxx|          1|
|          2|  yyy|          2|
|          3|  zzz|          2|
```

Nest table B into table A to get something like

```
[
    {
        "document_id": 1,
        "name": "aaa",
        "topics": [
            {
                "topic_id": 1,
                "name": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "document_id": 2,
        "name": "bbb",
        "topics": [
            {
                "topic_id": 2,
                "name": "yyy"
            },
            {
                "topic_id": 3,
                "name": "zzz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Note: I got the example from [this stakoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953820/merging-two-relational-pandas-dataframes-as-single-nested-json-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the result you're after:

```sql
SELECT
  a.document_id,
  ARBITRARY(a.name) AS name,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    CAST(
      ROW(topic_id, b.name)
      AS ROW(topic_id INTEGER, name VARCHAR)
    )
  ) AS topics
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b USING (document_id)
GROUP BY a.document_id
```

If you run that query and convert the result to a JSON array you should get the desired result from your question.

The core of the solution is to build up topic structs with `ROW` and aggregate these structs for each document. This is a confusing detail with Athena; DDL statements use Hive SQL where there's a type called `struct`, and queries uses Presto SQL where the equivalent concept is `ROW`, and it doesn't help that the names for the integer and string types are also different. In DDL the type would be `struct<topic_id:int,name:string>` but in DML it's `ROW(topic_id INTEGER, name VARCHAR)`.

I'm using `ARBITRARY` for the document name, but grouping by both document ID and name works too, the result will be the same.

When I run the query above on the data from your question I get this result:

```
document_id | name | topics
------------+------+-------
1           | aaa  | [{topic_id=1, name=xxx}]
2           | bbb  | [{topic_id=3, name=zzz}, {topic_id=2, name=yyy}]
```

And if you read that result set as JSON it you should get exactly what you posted, modulo ordering.

Comment: Many thanks. for the explanation, supper clear. I wonder whether this query is computationally expensive and athena is the right tool to do it, though. :)

Comment: Remember that with Athena you don't pay for compute, you pay for the amount of data scanned. Whether or not this is efficient or not depends on what you compare with. Joins are always going to be more expensive than single-table queries, but if you want to get the result you want this is not a bad way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible using [map_concat](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) and [array_agg](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html) - but I needed to cast topic_id as varchar:

```
with intermediate as
(
    select a.document_id,a.name
    ,MAP(array['topic_id'], array[cast(b.topic_id as varchar)]) topic_map
    ,MAP(array['name'], array[b.name]) name_map
    from table_a a
    left join table_b b
        on a.document_id = b.document_id
)
select i.document_id,i.name
,array_agg(cast(map_concat(topic_map,name_map) as json)) topics
from intermediate i
group by i.document_id,i.name;
```